# Visual basic text fields data to MS Word document

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-word

I need to create a form from which data have to be transferred to the MS Word document text fields

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MyApp1 As Object
    Dim MyDoc1 As Object
    MyApp1 = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    MyDoc1 = MyApp1.Documents.Open(C:\DSU.docx")
    MyDoc1.Field("w_VardasPavarde").Range = VardasPavarde.Text
    MyDoc1.Fields.Update()
    MyDoc1.Fields.Unlink()
    MyApp1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Code above opening word document, but fields lefts empty. Looking for advice.

Answer (score 0):

To get your code to work

- You would need to index the Fields collection
- To index the Fields COllection you have to use a number (a Long), not a text value
- But to do that, you have to know what number to use.

But what type of field are you trying to replace? Is it a REF field? If it is your choice and you need to use fields, you may be better off using { DOCVARIABLE } fields and setting the values of the corresponding Variables. Or, if you only need to support Windows Word 2007 and later, it might be better to use Content Controls linked to custom XML.